# Find limit $\lim_{h \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+3}+....+\frac{1}{2n+(2n-1)}$ using Riemann sum.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, riemann-integration

I want to find limit value using Riemann sum
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i = 1}^{2n} f(a+\frac{(b-a)k}{n})\cdot\frac{(b-a)}{n}= \int_a^b f(x)dx$$
**Question:**

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+3}+....+\frac{1}{2n+(2n-1)}$$

**Attempt:**

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{2+(2k-1)\frac{1}{n}}$$
>   i try to isolate 1/n but i cant find way to make this become $f(\frac{k}{n})$ since k is stuck in $2k-1$, can someone give me a hint? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:)**

Let $x_k=\dfrac{2k-1}{n}$ then $\Delta x=\dfrac{2}{n}$.

**Edit:(**

With $\Delta x=x_{k+1}-x_k=\dfrac{2k+1}{n}-\dfrac{2k-1}{n}=\dfrac{2}{n}$ we have by your notation
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{2+(2k-1)\frac{1}{n}}
&=
\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2}{n}\frac{1}{2+\frac{2k-1}{n}}\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2+x_k}\,\Delta x\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2\dfrac{1}{2+x}\,dx\\
&=
\color{blue}{\ln\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: sorry still dont get it..do you get $2/n$ out of the fraction?

Comment: @fiksx Full solution added.

Comment: thankyou so much!!, so here i can choose any $x_k$ but it will change the $\Delta x$ right? and also i try to substitute $0$ and $n$ to $k$ in $x_k=(2k-1)/n$ so it will produce $x_n=(2n-1)/n$ = $x_n=2-1/n$, how did you get 0 to 2 for the integral ?

Comment: $x_1=\dfrac1n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: oh got it!!!!! thankyou somuch!!!! so in problem like this, the main point is to get $1/n$ out of the fraction and the rest will follow(?)

Comment: Can you find upper limit?

Comment: In your attempt you got $\dfrac{1}{n}$ out of fraction with factorization, this made $\Delta x$ in Riemann sum! right

Comment: yes, so as long as i can factorize the $1/n$ as $\Delta x$ out of the fraction, i just have to choose my $x_k$, and according to my $x_k$ it will determine the $\Delta x$ that will be use in the equation right?

Comment: Exactly, except that $\dfrac1n$ made $\Delta x$ with factor $\dfrac12$ which we pull out of our sum!

Comment: ok thankyou so much!!! really appreciate for the help!!! thanks for answering my questions too ^^

Comment: You'r welcome :))

Answer (score 0):

The above limit can be written as $$\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n \sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{1}{1+2k/n}$$  because when in the limit $n \to \infty$ $1/n=0$.Now standard formula can be applied.

Comment: how to isolate $1/n$ ?

Comment: I didn't get you @fiksk

Comment: can you give me more hint? and how to make $\frac{1}{1+2k/n}$?